# HTML/JS output table not showing horizontal borders

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I can't figure out why my horizontal borders are not showing up with my output section. See code and screenshot below:
I would like to have horizontal borders and if possible keep the date fields from
wrapping into the next row below itself.
[image]

I would like to have horizontal borders and if possible keep the date fields from  wrapping into the next row below itself.

```
           <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display()" /></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="400px" align="center" colspan="40" table border="5">

    <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
        <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Time In</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Time Out</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
        <td align="center"><div id="displayarea1"></div></td>
        <td align="center"><div id="displayarea2"></div></td>
        <td align="center"><div id="displayarea3"></div></td>
        <td align="center"><div id="displayarea4"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

I would like to have horizontal borders and if possible keep the date fields from wrapping into the next row below itself.

```
function getValue() {
        var Items = "";
        var td1 = document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML.split("<br>");
        var td2 = document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML.split("<br>");
        var td3 = document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML.split("<br>");
        var td4 = document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML.split("<br>");
        var td5 = document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML.split("<br>");

        for (var i = 0; i < td1.length; i++) {
            if (td1[i])
                Items += td1[i] + " ,";
            if (td2[i])
                Items += td2[i] + " ,";
            if (td2[i])
                Items += td2[i] + " ,";
            if (td3[i])
                Items += td3[i] + " ,";
            if (td4[i])
                Items += td4[i] + " ";
            Items += "\n";
            
            
        }
        console.log(Items);
        return Items;
    }

    function display() {
        document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML += document.getElementById("fname").value + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("lname").value + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("sname").value + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("sname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML += document.getElementById("pname").value + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("pname").value = "";
        document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML += document.getElementById("jname").value + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("jname").value = "";
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you put any `<tr>` (table rows) in your table

Comment: you have 1 header row, and 1 row for data by the look of it, the data is split into lines using `<br>` ... that's not the same as creating a new row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest you start separating your data from your presentation of that data.

So, split your `display` function into two: `createRow` and `renderRows`. Likewise, `getValues` can just be `getRows`.

Note that this required a different way of doing things in your code, so I also refactored your HTML and CSS to bring it more in line with modern methods.

```js
function getRows(data) {
  return data.map(datum => Object.values(datum).join(',')).join('\n');
}

function createRow(data) {
  const datum = {
    fname: document.getElementById("fname").value,
    lname: document.getElementById("lname").value,
    sname: new Date(document.getElementById("sname").valueAsNumber).toLocaleString(),
    pname: new Date(document.getElementById("pname").valueAsNumber).toLocaleString(),
    jname: document.getElementById("jname").value
  };
  data.push(datum);
  document.getElementById("dataForm").reset();
  renderRows(data);
}

function renderRows(data) {
  const body = document.getElementById("renderedData");
  body.innerHTML = "";
  for (let datum of data) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let tdFName = document.createElement('td');
    tdFName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datum.fname));
    tr.appendChild(tdFName);
    let tdLName = document.createElement('td');
    tdLName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datum.lname));
    tr.appendChild(tdLName);
    let tdSName = document.createElement('td');
    tdSName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datum.sname));
    tr.appendChild(tdSName);
    let tdPName = document.createElement('td');
    tdPName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datum.pname));
    tr.appendChild(tdPName);
    let tdJName = document.createElement('td');
    tdJName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(datum.jname));
    tr.appendChild(tdJName);
    body.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const data = [];
  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    createRow(data);
  });
  document.getElementById('getData').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(getRows(data));
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem;
}
.control-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

fieldset button {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<form id="dataForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Data</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="fname">Name:</label>
      <input id="fname" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="lname">Company:</label>
      <input id="lname" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="sname">Time In:</label>
      <input id="sname" type="datetime-local">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="pname">Time Out:</label>
      <input id="pname" type="datetime-local">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="jname">Description of Work:</label>
      <textarea id="jname"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<table width="400px" align="center" colspan="40" table border="5">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;" id='header'>
      <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Time In</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Time Out</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="renderedData">
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="getData">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: What did you mean separate data from presentation data? I'm working in Notepad++ currently and just starting out.

Comment: @Zedu The idea is that the data you want to work with is not tied to the DOM. That is, the elements on the screen. So in my answer, the data are stored in an array as objects. If you wanted to, you could use that data to create a chart instead of or in addition to a table. It makes it easier to work with the data too; for instance, sorting is easier, since it's just sorting objects in an array, rather than trying to sort table rows.

Answer (score 1):

To get borders for all cells, add this at the top of your html code (inside the `head`):

```
<style>
  table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
  }
  td {
    border: 1px solid #555;
  }
</style>
```

Adjust the border thickness, style and color as you like (in the `border` setting of `td`)

Comment: This won't help if the OP is not using table cells, but rather using `br` elements in an existing cell to simulate rows of data.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - sorry ... my page screwed up and I thought this comment was on my answer!! many apologies for my senior moment!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX No worries, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to add a row with each addition using the   element - available in all good browsers (not so fast Internet Explorer, I wasn't talking to you)

I've also changed how to read the values

note, using `class` instead of `id` in the cells in the rows - to make it easy to get them all with minimal change to your code

Although, personally I'd get the row data data differently (shown in `alternativeGetValues`)

```js
function getValue() {
    var Items = "";
    var td1 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".displayarea")].map(e => e.innerHTML);
    var td2 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".displayarea1")].map(e => e.innerHTML);
    var td3 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".displayarea2")].map(e => e.innerHTML);
    var td4 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".displayarea3")].map(e => e.innerHTML);
    var td5 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".displayarea4")].map(e => e.innerHTML);

    for (var i = 0; i < td1.length; i++) {
        if (td1[i])
            Items += td1[i] + " ,";
        if (td2[i])
            Items += td2[i] + " ,";
        if (td3[i])
            Items += td3[i] + " ,";
        if (td4[i])
            Items += td4[i] + " ,";
        if (td5[i])
            Items += td5[i] + " ";
        Items += "\n";

    }
    console.log(Items);
    return Items;
}

function display() {
    const template = document.getElementById("row");
    const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    const additem = (dest, src) => {
        const s = document.querySelector(src);
        clone.querySelector(dest).innerHTML = s.value;
        s.value = "";
    };
    additem(".displayarea", "#fname");
    additem(".displayarea1", "#lname");
    additem(".displayarea2", "#sname");
    additem(".displayarea3", "#pname");
    additem(".displayarea4", "#jname");
    template.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', clone.firstElementChild);
}

// IMHO this is better
function alternateGetValue() {
    const Items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.data')]
        .map(row => [...row.querySelectorAll('td>div')]
            .map(d => d.textContent).join(',')
        ).join('\n');
    console.log(Items);
    return Items;
}
```

```css
.wide {
  min-width:12em;
}
```

```html
F: <input id="fname"> <br>
L: <input id="lname"> <br>
S: <input id="sname"> <br>
P: <input id="pname"> <br>
J: <input id="jname"> <br>
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="display()"/>
<input type="button" value="show" onclick="getValue()"/>
<input type="button" value="Better" onclick="alternateGetValue()"/>
<table width="400px" align="center" colspan="40" table border="5">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;" id='header'>
        <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
        <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Time In</b></td>
        <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Time Out</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template id="row">
        <tr style="background-color:#8F8FBC;" class="data">
            <td align="center"><div class="displayarea"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div class="displayarea1"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div class="displayarea2"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div class="displayarea3"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div class="displayarea4"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```